# Show most tagged taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to achieve a list of most tagged taxonomy tagged in last 24 hours. For an instance:

China from taxonomy country has been tagged 20 times
 Eminem from taxonomy music has been tagged 15 times
 Chelsea from taxonomy football has been tagged 10 times
 USA from taxonomy country has been tagged 12 times

The result should show list something like: China Eminem USA Chelsea

I ended up with this:

```
  <?php $terms = get_terms( array( 
        'taxonomy' => 'country','music','football',
       'orderby'    => 'count',
        'monthnum'  => date('m'),
        'day'       => date('d'),
        'year'      => date('Y')
     ); 
       $loop = new WP_Query($args);
       if ($loop->have_posts()) :
           while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```